# power series of $\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)^2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I need to find the power series of $\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)^2$ around $0$, and find its radius of convergence.
Also the function is defined to be $1$ in $z=0$.
My guess about the radius is infinity, but I'm stuck in the power series.
This is what I've done so far:

$$\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)^2 = \left(\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\cdots}z\right)^2$$
$$=\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}+\cdots\right)^2$$
$$=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2$$

could really use some help. Thanks very much!

Comment: Use $\sin^2z=\frac12(1-\cos 2z)$.

Comment: If you know the function is analytic everywhere in $\mathbb C$, then it follows that the Maclaurin series has infinite radius of convergence.  Analytic everywhere is easy except possibly at $z=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *Lord Shark the Unknown*'s hint we can rewrite the problem in the following way

$$\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)^2=\frac1{2z^2}(1-\cos 2z)$$

Utilizing the well known Taylor Series of the cosine function this further becomes

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2z^2}(1-\cos 2z)&=\frac1{2z^2}\left(1-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2z^2}-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2z)^{2n-2}}{(2n)!}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2z)^{2n-2}}{(2n)!}
\end{align}$$

> $$\left(\frac{\sin z}z\right)^2=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{4^n z^{2n}}{(2n+2)!}$$

Regarding the radius of convergence one could apply the ratio test to verfity that it is actually infinity.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! it helped me a lot. notice a small mistake in line 2, where you should multiply the series by (1/2) and not 2, not that I mind of course.

Comment: @Roee No problem. Actually it is right like this. Note that $$\frac1{2z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\frac{\color{red}{2}}{(2z)^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\color{red}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2z)^{2n-2}}{(2n)!}$$ I the first place I have made a mistake within this step leading to the power series of $1/4(\sin z/z)^2$ instead of the wanted for $(\sin z/z)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\ell\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{sine-power-ser-expan-eq}
\biggl(\frac{\sin z}{z}\biggr)^{\ell}
=1+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j}\frac{T(\ell+2j,\ell)}{\binom{\ell+2j}{\ell}} \frac{(2z)^{2j}}{(2j)!},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{T(n-k)-EF-Eq(3.1)}
T(n,\ell)=\frac1{\ell!} \sum_{j=0}^{\ell}(-1)^{j}\binom{\ell}{j}\biggl(\frac{\ell}2-j\biggr)^n
\end{equation}
with $T(0,0)=1$ and $T(n,0)=0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Reference

1. Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, *Several series expansions for real powers and several formulas for partial Bell polynomials of sinc and sinhc functions in terms of central factorial and Stirling numbers of second kind*, arXiv preprint (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612v4 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.

Comment: It is very enlightening to see someone who made the formula relating to this question answering it :)